# Errors on System.IO.FileStream CSV file creation and System.IO.File.Delete

Tags: ios, vb.net, csv, filestream, delete-file

In an old VB.NET code (VS 2008) I use this code:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(sFilePath) Then
    System.IO.File.Delete(sFilePath)
End If

Dim Fs As New System.IO.FileStream(sFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)

Fs.Close()
```

If the file exists then on this line:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(sFilePath)
```

I get this error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

When I manually remove the file, then on this line:

```
Dim Fs As New System.IO.FileStream(sFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
```

I get the error:

> The file already exists

Although it doesn't.

The code always (for 8 years now) worked perfectly. Nothing in this part of the code has been changed.

So what is going on here?

Comment: Is the value of `sFilePath` absolutely definitely without a doubt what you think it is?

Comment: Consider implementing `Using`...`Using fs As New FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write) End Using`. However that code runs fine without the errors so maybe `sFilePath` is not what you think it is.